# the javascript object model: strange constructor property

Tags: javascript

I find the behaviour of this piece of code puzzling, why is the constructor of `child` not `Child`? Can someone please explain this to me?

```
function Parent() {
    this.prop1 = "value1";
    this.prop2 = "value2";
}

function Child() {
    this.prop1 = "value1b";
    this.prop3 = "value3";
}
Child.prototype = new Parent();

var child = new Child();

// this is expected
console.log(child instanceof Child); //true
console.log(child instanceof Parent); //true

// what??
console.log(child.constructor == Child); //false
console.log(child.constructor == Parent); //true
```

Comment: This question appears to be a dup of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479349/constructors-and-inheritance-in-js) - but I find this question's answers more useful. +1s all around :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Pointy has pointed out, [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901802/the-javascript-object-model-strange-constructor-property/3901827#3901827)

> The "constructor" property is a
>   reference to the function that created
>   the object's prototype, not the object
>   itself.

The usual way to deal with this is to augment the object's prototype `constructor` property after assigning to the `prototype`

```
function Parent() {
    this.prop1 = "value1";
    this.prop2 = "value2";
}

function Child() {
    this.prop1 = "value1b";
    this.prop3 = "value3";
}
Child.prototype = new Parent();

// set the constructor to point to Child function
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var child = new Child();

// this is expected
console.log(child instanceof Child); //true
console.log(child instanceof Parent); //true

// corrected
console.log(child.constructor == Child); // now true
console.log(child.constructor == Parent); // now false

console.log(Child.prototype.constructor); // Child
console.log(Parent.prototype.constructor); // Parent
```

I can't recommend Stoyan Stefanov's [Object Oriented JavaScript](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Object-Oriented-Javascript-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/1847194141/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1286739557&sr=1-1) enough which covers Prototype and Inheritance in some detail (get the second edition if you can as it addresses some critiques of the first edition).

Comment: thank you for the tip, maybe I'll order it, although the 2nd edition does not seem to be ready yet.

Comment: this solution means that if I were to create a sibling of Child, i.e another `function Sibling(){}; Sibling.prototype = /* expression */; var sibling = new Sibling()`, then `expression` would have to be `new Parent()` and not the same parent object as Child, i.e `Child.prototype != Sibling.prototype`. Is this how it is usually done? I like the philosophy of prototypal inheritence but this seems like a very convoluted way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't be able to assign the same instance of `Parent` to the `prototype` of both `Child` and `Sibling` as any changes to the `prototype` of either Child or Sibling will affect the other. For example, setting the `constructor` of one will change it for both.

Answer (score 4):

The "constructor" property is a reference to the function that created the object's **prototype**, not the object itself.

Comment: which in this case comes from the object returned by the `Parent` constructor function and assigned to the `Child.prototype`

Comment: Right, exactly.  I've been trying to find a site/blog I read a few months ago that had a good explanation (with good diagrams), and if I do I'll link it.

Comment: no, the object itself is `child`, but it was constructed by `Child` (note the capital letter). It seems like a(nother) design flaw of JS that this would point to the object's prototype's constructor and not the object's constructor.