# Why do we need the isPrototypeOf at all?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

[this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/IsPrototypeOf) states:

> Note: isPrototypeOf differs from
>   instanceof operator. In the expression
>   object instanceof AFunction, the
>   object prototype chain is checked
>   against AFunction.prototype, not
>   against AFunction itself

Ok I don't really get what they are trying to tell us. Isn't `object instanceof AFunction` exactly the same as `AFunction.prototype.isPrototypeOf(object)? or am I wrong?

Why do we need the `isPrototypeOf` at all?

If i ever need to do `p.isPrototypeOf(o)` couldn't I just do `o instanceof p.constructor` ?

Addtionally, is `p.isPrototypeOf(o)` functionally equivalent to `p===Object.getPrototypeOf(o)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Object constructors are funky things. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901802/the-javascript-object-model-strange-constructor-property/3901894#3901894):

> As Pointy has pointed out, [in his
>   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901802/the-javascript-object-model-strange-constructor-property/3901894#3901894)
>
> > The "constructor" property is a
> >     reference to the function that created
> >     the object's prototype, not the object
> >     itself.
>
> The usual way to deal with this is to
>   augment the object's prototype
>   `constructor` property after assigning
>   to the `prototype`.

An object's constructor is not read-only, which is why this is possible to do at all. I could assign any value to `p.constructor` after `p` is created, and this would completely break using

```
o instanceof p.constructor
```

instead of

```
p.isPrototypeOf(o)
```

#### Further reading

- [`constructor` @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)
- [What it the significance of the Javascript constructor property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property)
- [OO Programming in JS](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm)
- [Constructors considered mildly confusing](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html)

---

***Edit*** re: OP edit

> Addtionally, is `p.isPrototypeOf(o)` functionally equivalent to `p===Object.getPrototypeOf(o)`?

Those are more similar than your original question, aside from the fact that `Object.getPrototypeOf` wasn't introduced until JavaScript 1.8.1? See [John Resig - `Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/). Perhaps more relevant, the two functions are different in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)! <sub><sup>(warning, PDF link)</sup></sub>

[image: 15.2.3.2 Object.getPrototypeOf]

[image: 15.2.4.6 Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf]

Comment: Also, isPrototypeOf will check the whole prototype chain, while p===Object.getPrototypeOf(o) only checks for the top level

Answer (score 7):

I think the most important distinction here is that the isPrototypeOf method allows you to check if an object inherits directly from another object. Consider the following:

```
var t = new Object();
var f = new Object();
var c = Object.create(t);

c instanceof f.constructor; // true
c instanceof t.constructor; // true
f.isPrototypeOf(c); // false
t.isPrototypeOf(c); // true
```

As you can see the constructor is only the function that instantiated the object. Not the implementation specifier. So if `t.y = function(){ return true; }` and `f.y = function(){ return false; }` and I needed to check that `c` would return the appropriate implementation through it's prototype chain, `instanceof` wouldn't help very much.

Comment: ok am I right to say that f.isPrototypeOf(c) is exactly the same as c.__proto__===f

Answer (score 0):

instanceOf --> This object (or the objects it was derived from ) used the named object as a prototype

isPrototypeOf --> This object was used by the named Object (or the Objects it was derived from) as a prototype.

ie.

instanceOf is querying the objects ancestors.

IsPrototypeOf is querying the objects descendants.