# isPrototypeOf() usage when dealing with inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
//I have this base Rectangle constructor function
function Rectangle (length, width){
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}

Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function (){
    return this.length * this.width;
};

//Creating Square constructor function that will inherit from Rectangle...

function Square(size){
    this.length = size;
    this.width  = size;
}

Square.prototype = new Rectangle(); 
Square.prototype.constructor = Square;

//creating rectangle and square instances
var rect = new Rectangle(5, 10);
var square = new Square(6);

console.log(rect.getArea());  //50
console.log(square.getArea());  //36 

console.log(Rectangle.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Square.prototype)); //true

console.log(Rectangle.prototype.isPrototypeOf(rect)); //true

console.log(Square.prototype.isPrototypeOf(square));  //true
```

my question is when i do the below `console.log()`, I expected it to print `false`. However, I got `true`.

```
console.log(Rectangle.prototype.isPrototypeOf(square));  //true
```

1) Does this mean `isPrototypeOf` goes to multiple levels?

2) if `isPrototypeOf` goes multiple levels, what is the point of using `isPrototypeOf` instead of using `instanceof`?

I've read this [Why do we need the isPrototypeOf at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972991/why-do-we-need-the-isprototypeof-at-all) but didn't understand how it applies in my use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. isPrototypeOf checks if an object is within another object's prototype chain so yes it does go multiple levels

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf

2. They can be used for the same purpose. You can do `square instanceof Square` or `Square.prototype.isPrototypeOf(square)` but as you can see, `instanceof` has a specific purpose to match objects with their constructors where as isPrototypeOf can be used more broadly to check if any object is within the prototype chain of another.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Answer (score 1):

The `isPrototypeOf()` method tests for an object in another object's prototype chain

Here in Your Code

```
console.log(Rectangle.prototype.isPrototypeOf(square)); // true
```

> It prints true because **Square** Method is in the the chain of
>   **getArea** Method and the **getArea** is the prototype method of Rectangle

```
Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function (){
    return this.length * this.width;
};
```

For Example According to [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf)

```
 function Fee() {
  // ...
}

function Fi() {
  // ...
}
Fi.prototype = new Fee();

function Fo() {
  // ...
}
Fo.prototype = new Fi();

function Fum() {
  // ...
}
Fum.prototype = new Fo()
```

*Later on down the road, if you instantiate Fum and need to check if
 Fi's prototype exists within the Fum prototype chain, you could do
 this:*

```
var fum = new Fum();
// ...

if (Fi.prototype.isPrototypeOf(fum)) {
  // do something safe
}
```