# Javascript strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Can anyone explain this code to me

```
var ParentClass = function(){
}

var ChildClass = function(){
}

//ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();

var child = new ChildClass();
alert(child.constructor === ChildClass); // alert true
```

But

```
var ParentClass = function(){
}

var ChildClass = function(){
}

ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();

var child = new ChildClass();
alert(child.constructor === ChildClass); // alert false
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [the javascript object model: strange constructor property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901802/the-javascript-object-model-strange-constructor-property). **tl;dr** _"The "constructor" property is a reference to the function that created the object's prototype, not the object itself."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`constructor` is a property of the `prototype` object:

```
var ChildClass = function(){
}

alert(ChildClass.prototype.constructor == ChildClass); // alert true
```

The relationship is now like this:

```
  +-------------------+           +--------------------+
  |                   |           |                    |
  |ChildClass instance|---------->|ChildClass protoype |
  |                   |           |  constructor prop  |
  +-------------------+           +--------------------+
```

This property points indeed to the `ChildClass` function.

If you override `ChildClass.prototype`, then `child.constructor` will be looked up in the prototype chain and will refer to:

```
ParentClass.prototype.constructor
```

as `ChildClass.prototype` is now an instance of `ParentClass` which inherits from `ParentClass.prototype`:

```
  +-------------------+      +--------------------+      +---------------------+
  |                   |      |                    |      |                     |
  |ChildClass instance| ---> |ParentClass instance| ---> |ParentClass prototype|
  |                   |      |                    |      |   constructor  prop |
  +-------------------+      +--------------------+      +---------------------+
```

`ParentClass.prototype.constructor` will of course point to `ParentClass`.

Comment: Thanks. I just thout that constructor is the object's property. Now i know that condstructor is prototype's property.

Answer (score 3):

Well because in that case you borrow the constructor form ParentClass! It's a pattern i'v read of in the book "javascript patterns" (very good book on javascript).

In fact:

```
var ParentClass = function(){
}

var ChildClass = function(){
}

ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();

var child = new ChildClass();
alert(child.constructor === ParentClass)
```

Alerts true!

Comment: I thout constructor is the function that constructs this object (child in my place)

Comment: Not in this case: you overwrite the  constructor as well.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior here isn't strange at all.  Normally you see people do things like this:

```
var ChildClass = function () {

}

ChildClass.prototype.OftUsedMethod = function () {
  // Something you'll want to be able to do here for every instance of
  // ChildClass, but that you don't want separate instances of the function
  // for.
}
```

But because you've assigned directly to `ChildClass.prototype` instead of assigning to a member attribute you've effectively overwritten the base prototype for ChildClass.

Answer (score 1):

When you overwrite an object's prototype, it overwrites the constructor as well. You can set it back to the original, however. This is done is various libraries and snippets such John Resig's [Simple Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).

```
var ParentClass = function(){
}

var ChildClass = function(){
}

ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;

var child = new ChildClass();
alert(child.constructor === ChildClass); // alert true
```